# Service unavailable when deploying event receiver to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin, event-receivers

I'm trying to deploy a simple remote event receiver (as per http://sundarnarasiman.net/?p=224) to a hosted Sharepoint 2013 server, for which I have admin rights.

However, when building/deploying this in VS2013, I get the error:

> The HTTP service located at
>   `http://[host_address]:32843/0dcd895ab64d4fd49f04b6368234be82/AppMng.svc` is
>   unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because
>   no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please
>   ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again
>   later.

Navigating to the given Site Contents page, the app exists but is greyed out as unavailable.

Is there some kind of security setting that I am missing?

Comment: Did you provision the App Management Service Application in Manage Service Applications and start the App Management Service in Manage Services on Server? This is done via Central Admin.

Comment: No, I'm not sure what you mean here, what does this entail?

Comment: The Service must be started and the Service Application must be created in Central Administration. Go to Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Services on Server to start the App Management Service. Go to Central Admin -> Application Management -> Manage Service Applications, New menu, and create an App Management Service.

Comment: Thanks. Yes there already seems to be an App Management Service running - where the services' database name is `AppMng_Service_DB_2c847499dd0a4a12aa8367e18ae2e062.`

Comment: Next step would be to make sure the IIS Application Pool is running in the IIS Manager. The App Pool will have a random GUID identifier (without the dashes).

Comment: Yes there are several, but none with the guid `0dcd895ab64d4fd49f04b6368234be82` (Assuming that's what my app is trying to reference). Would I need to create a new App Pool with this guid?

Comment: Just make sure they're running, it won't be the same identifier. Is the Service Application and SA Proxy also Online in Manage Service Apps?

Comment: I have Search Service Application (and Proxy) there and running, but no Service Application

Comment: Sorry, the App Management Service Application and Proxy.

Comment: Yes they are both running

Comment: Have you changed url in event receiver element file?

Comment: The url in each event receiver item is: 

`<Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/RemoteEventReceiver.svc</Url>`

Where I'm assuming this `remoteAppUrl` property is taken from the project settings.